# I am creating code for zone, circle, district, block, GP in XMLHttpRequest()

Tags: javascript, php

I am creating code for zone, circle, district, block, GP in XMLHttpRequest()
Here circle and district is coming as per zone and block will come as per district and GP will come as per block.

Circle is coming perfect, block and GP were coming as per district. But now district is not coming as per circle so block and GP is also blank.

Following is my code:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function getXMLHTTP() { //fuction to return the xml http object
        var xmlhttp=false;  
        try{
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        catch(e)    {       
            try{            
                xmlhttp= new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch(e){
                try{
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                }
                catch(e1){
                    xmlhttp=false;
                }
            }
        }

        return xmlhttp;
    }

    function getCircle(zoneId) {        

        var strURL="http://localhost//sbmpunjab/website_control/admin_form/circle_report.php?zone="+zoneId;
        var req = getXMLHTTP();

        if (req) {

            req.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (req.readyState == 4) {
                    // only if "OK"
                    if (req.status == 200) {

                            var returnedData = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
                            $('#Circlediv select[name=circle]').html(returnedData.circle);

                           document.getElementById('Districtdiv').innerHTML='<select name="district"><option>Select district</option></select>';

                    } else {
                        alert("Problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
                    }
                }               
            }           
            req.open("GET", strURL, true);
            req.send(null);
        }       
    }

    function getDistrict(zoneId,circleId) {     

        var strURL="http://localhost//sbmpunjab/website_control/admin_form/district_report.php?zone="+zoneId+"&circle="+circleId;
        var req = getXMLHTTP();

        if (req) {

            req.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (req.readyState == 4) {
                    // only if "OK"
                if (req.status == 200) {    
                   var returnedData = JSON.parse(req.responseText);                 
                    $('#Districtdiv select[name=district]').html(returnedData.district);                                        
                    } else {
                        alert("Problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
                    }
                }               
            }           
            req.open("GET", strURL, true);
            req.send(null);
        }

    }

function getState(districtId) {     

        var strURL="http://localhost//sbmpunjab/website_control/admin_form/constituency_report.php?district="+districtId;
        var req = getXMLHTTP();

        if (req) {

            req.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (req.readyState == 4) {
                    // only if "OK"
                    if (req.status == 200) {

                            var returnedData = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
                            $('#Constituencydiv select[name=constituency]').html(returnedData.constituency);
                            $('#Blockdiv').html(returnedData.block);
                            $('#Divisionsdiv select[name=divisions]').html(returnedData.divisions);

                              document.getElementById('GramPanchdiv').innerHTML='<select name="grampanch"><option>Select Gram Panchayat</option></select>';         

                    } else {
                        alert("Problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
                    }
                }               
            }           
            req.open("GET", strURL, true);
            req.send(null);
        }       
    }

    function getCity(districtId,blockId) {      
        var 
        strURL="http://localhost//sbmpunjab/website_control/admin_form/village_report.php?district="+districtId+"&block="+blockId;

        var req = getXMLHTTP();

        if (req) {

            req.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (req.readyState == 4) {
                    // only if "OK"
                    if (req.status == 200) {    
      var returnedData = JSON.parse(req.responseText);                  
      $('#GramPanchdiv select[name=grampanch]').html(returnedData.GramPanch);                                       
                    } else {
                        alert("Problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
                    }
                }               
            }           
            req.open("GET", strURL, true);
            req.send(null);
        }

    }
</script>
```

**circle_report.php**

```
<?php
$zone=intval($_GET['zone']);

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '','sbmpunjab'); 
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
}
$query="SELECT * FROM zsk_circle WHERE zone_id='$zone'";
$result1=mysqli_query($con,$query);



$circle = '<select name="circle" onchange="getDistrict('.$zone.', this.value)">
          <option value="">Select circle</option>';
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)){
    $circle .= "<option value='".$row['id']."'>".$row['circle']."</option>";
}
$circle .= '</select>';

$returnArray = array();
$returnArray['circle'] = $circle;

echo json_encode($returnArray);
exit;
?>
```

**district_report.php**

```
<?php

$zone=intval($_GET['zone']);
$circle=intval($_GET['circle']);

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '','sbmpunjab'); 

if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
}
//mysqli_select_db($con,'sbmpunjab');

$query="SELECT * FROM zsk_district WHERE circle_id='$circle'";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$query);

$district = '<select name="district"><option value="">Select district</option>';
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $district .= "<option value='".$row['id']."'>".$row['district']."</option></select>";
}

$returnArray = array();
$returnArray['district'] = $district;

echo json_encode($returnArray);
exit;
```

**constituency_report.php**

```
<?php
$district=intval($_GET['district']);
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '','sbmpunjab'); 
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
}
$query="SELECT * FROM zsk_constituency_list WHERE district_id='$district'";
$result1=mysqli_query($con,$query);

$query="SELECT * FROM zsk_blocks WHERE district_id='$district'";
$result2=mysqli_query($con,$query);

$query="SELECT * FROM zsk_divisions_list WHERE district_id='$district'";
$result3=mysqli_query($con,$query);

$constituency = '<option value="">Select constituency</option>';
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)){
    $constituency .= "<option value='".$row['id']."'>".$row['constituency_name']."</option>";
}

$block = '<select name="block" onchange="getCity('.$district.', this.value)">
          <option value="">Select block</option>';
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)){
    $block .= "<option value='".$row['id']."'>".$row['block_name']."</option>";
}
$block .= '</select>';

$divisions = '<option value="">Select divisions</option>';
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result3)){
    $divisions .= "<option value='".$row['id']."'>".$row['division_name']."</option>";
}

$returnArray = array();
$returnArray['constituency'] = $constituency;
$returnArray['block'] = $block;
$returnArray['divisions'] = $divisions;

echo json_encode($returnArray);
exit;
?>
```

**village_report.php**

```
<?php

$district=intval($_GET['district']);
$block=intval($_GET['block']);
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '','sbmpunjab'); 

if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
}
//mysqli_select_db($con,'sbmpunjab');

$query="SELECT * FROM zsk_gram_panchayat_list WHERE block_id='$block'";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$query);

$GramPanch = '<select name="grampanch"><option value="">Select gram panchayat</option>';
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $GramPanch .= "<option value='".$row['id']."'>".$row['village_name']."</option></select>";
}

$returnArray = array();
$returnArray['GramPanch'] = $GramPanch;

echo json_encode($returnArray);
exit;
```

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. How we're supposed to know what's coming from your `village_report.php`? Seems relevant to understand your problem.

Comment: HI alan, i have added all files used in it. Please check.